# Shell command for copying the contents of one folder to another

Tags: shell

Due to the way the Plesk Extension on my web server works, I am trying to write a shell command that fires after a deployment. This simply needs to copy the contents of one folder to another.

Currently, I am using this:

```
cp -r /deployed-site/public/ /httpdocs/
```

However, this only seems to work if the destination folder is empty. Every time a deployment occurs, I want the contents of the first folder copied and pasted into the second?

Comment: did you try cp -rf ??

Comment: Maybe consider using `rsync` instead as it will only copy differences and hopefully be faster.

Comment: To add to Mark comments, rsync will also delete files if they're not in the origin directory.

Comment: 'rsync' sound like a much better solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I keep original build code inside a password protected folder build-src

Then I use :

`rm -rf /httpdocs`

`cp -r /httpdocs/build-src /httpdocs/`

I am using this on Plesk remote repository in Deploy Actions

Answer (score -1):

I would say it's better to clean the destination folder before copying files:

```
rm -rf /httpdocs
cp -r /deployed-site/public/ /httpdocs/
```

Comment: This would delete everything and then copy files over. Hence my site would temporarily be unavailable. Not great for a website